# Why nslookup is not passing throunght my local CNTLM proxy?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, proxy, cntlm

I am not so into networking and I have the following problem. I am working on an **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** server inside a network of my customer.

Here I have the following problems that seems to be related to the DNS resolution.

If I perform this command:

```
my.username@VHCLWSO2AS02:~$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

it seems that **nslookup** is not working so I obtain a timeout.

The stange thing is that if I perform a **wget** command into my shell it works fine, infact:

```
my.username@VHCLWSO2AS02:~$ wget google.com
--2020-02-17 15:19:53--  http://google.com/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2020-02-17 15:19:53--  http://www.google.com/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                  [ <=>                                                                           ]  11.52K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2020-02-17 15:19:53 (214 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [11800]
```

As you can see it works fine. My original doubt is: why **nslookup** is not working but **wget** using the same **google.com** name it is working fine?

Looking inside the output of the **wget** output it seems to me that it is passing through a proxy. In particular I think that it should be a **CNTLM** proxy installed on the same machine (running on the **3128** port of the same machine: **127.0.0.1**). It make sense because on the customer networks should use a Windows firewall requiring authentication in order to access to the Internet.

So my assumption is that, for some reaon that I don't know, **nslookup** is not passing throunght this **CNTLM** proxy so it is not working.

Is my reasoning correct? In case why **nslookup** is not passing throunght my proxy (as done by wget)? What am I missing? In case do you have some ideas to solve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You're using an HTTP proxy, that is, a proxy meant to relay HTTP requests – but **nslookup isn't an HTTP client** in the first place, so it doesn't even look at your proxy settings.

Although technically HTTP proxies *can* often carry TCP streams using the 'CONNECT' method – which is how they usually handle HTTPS sites without having to break TLS security. – most non-HTTP tools do not support this natively, because 1) most proxies are configured to *only* allow stream connections to the HTTPS port; 2) this method cannot carry UDP datagrams (nslookup wants to use UDP as well as TCP).

If only TCP is wanted (and if the proxy *allows* connections to the needed port), you can probably use wrappers such as `proxytunnel`.

wget works because it doesn't actually have to perform DNS resolution for "google.com" at all: it simply gives the raw URL `http://google.com` to the proxy, and the proxy makes its own DNS lookup.